Woocommerce automatically assigns orders to different shop managers
In WooCommerce, We currently run a shop with 2 shop managers, and based on fairness, I want them to be able to basically receive the same number of customers and process orders.
My current idea is to check the last digit of the billing phone number of the order and if it is the base number (1,3,5,7,9) then assign it to the first shop manager.
Or of it is an even number (2,4,6,8,0) it will be assigned to the second shop manager.
If this is difficult to achieve, then is it possible to do that by the last digit of the order number?
From  How can I assign an order to a certain shop manager in Woocommerce
I found this code is similar one, but assign by countries doesn't suit my store.
function before_checkout_create_order($order, $data) {

        $country = $order->billing_country;
        $store_manager_id = '';

        $belgium_region = ['BE', 'NL', 'DE'];
        $czech_region = ['CZ', 'AT', 'SI', 'HU'];
        $uk_region = ['GB'];

        if (in_array($country, $belgium_region)) {
            // Manually assigning the _store_manager_id using the user id, yours will differ
            $store_manager_id = 7;
        } else if (in_array($country, $czech_region)) {
            $store_manager_id = 3;
        } else if (in_array($country, $uk_region)) {
            $store_manager_id = 2;
        } else {
            $store_manager_id = 1;
        }

        $order->update_meta_data('_store_manager_id', $store_manager_id);
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);


Try the following that will assign alternatively one of the two shop managers to the current order by adding its user ID as custom metadata (the code is commented):
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'assign_order_to_shop_manager');
function assign_order_to_shop_manager( $order ) {
    // Define the shop manager user IDs below
    $shop_manager_user_id1 = 12;
    $shop_manager_user_id2 = 18;

    // Get the last (previous) order assigned User (from options custom field)
    $assigned_to = (int) get_option('last_order_assigned_user_id'); 

    // Check the previous assigned shop manager to switch to the other shop manager for this order
    if ( $assigned_to === $shop_manager_user_id1 ) {
        $assigned_to = $shop_manager_user_id2;
    } else {
        $assigned_to = $shop_manager_user_id1;
    }
    // Assign this order to one of the shop managers user Id (alternatively)
    $order->update_meta_data('_shop_manager_user_id', $assigned_to);

    // Update the assigned shop manager as the last order assigned (to options custom field)
    update_option('last_order_assigned_user_id', $assigned_to);
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
